# Protobuf: Uncaught reference error: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get protobuf to run in typescript.

The official Google Documentation says to simply use `npm install google-protobuf` and then to `require('google-protobuf')`.

I'm unexperienced with npm, so I ran into several problems there. First of all, `require('google-protobuf')` returned an error 404, because the file was not found. I instead opted to require the file manually, so I sourced it in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js"></script>
```

This *should* work right?
What instead happens is that I get an `Uncaught reference error: exports is not defined`. How do I even begin to debug this? I tried to take a look at the google-protobuf.js file and found a few `exports` statements, but I don't know what I'm expected to do here.

If it helps at all, here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to actually require 'google-protobuf'. You should not have gotten a 404 error when requiring it. You should try to focus your effort there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using typescript. Try
`import protobuf = reqquire('google-protobuf')`

or install the types via `npm install @types/google-protobuf'` and include it with `import * as protobuf from 'google-protobuf'`

The include in the HTML does not work, because the js files use imports and the dependencies are not resolved.

If you want to use this on the client side, you can finally build your fronted js file with browserify.

Answer (score 1):

First, please make sure you have a proper environment. I suggest you to:

1. Install and/or update **node**
2. Install and/or update **ts-node**

Then, try the following solutions:

### JavaScript (ES5) + CommonJS

```
// test.js
var protobuf = require('google-protobuf');
console.log(protobuf);
```

Run the script with `node test.js`.

### TypeScript + ES6 modules

```
// test.ts
import * as protobuf from 'google-protobuf';
console.log(protobuf);
```

Run the script with `ts-node test.ts`.

If you see a regular object in your terminal, congrats! The module is working. But now, if you want to use it in your browser, you will need module loaders/bundlers like **Browserify** or **Webpack**...